# What to do with a begging cat

Tags: cats

When will my cat stop begging and meowing for food when we stop her steroid medication? Why is my cat not happy with a meal 3 times a day?

Comment: Translation: "Hooman! Thou shall feed thy master at once!" Had the same with our late cat, even without medication. 

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the cat.

Some, especially ex-ferals, are food-insecure and don't quite trust that the next meal will arrive on time.

Some just enjoy nibbling all day -- I can relate to that!

Some are actually more interested in getting the human to acknowledge them than in the food.

Some have other reasons.

You are certainly not required to feed the cat any time it wants to be fed. If you're serving wet food, two meals a day is plenty. If you're serving dry food, some cats are ok with a continuous feeding bin; others overeat and need to be given a measured amount in a specific schedule (by hand or via machine).

Yes, the cat may complain. If you stop responding to the complaints by rewarding them with food, and keep a regular feeding schedule, the cat will generally figure out that complaining doesn't work and stop demanding food between meals.

That may not keep it from demanding attention. Again, you need to decide whether or not to reward that behavior, and if not be careful not to reinforce it.